# Bootstrap input-group-sm and input-group-append not working

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

i want to use a small input-group with an appended icon or button in Bootstrap 4. But when i use the example code and add the "-sm" to the input-group class the button is placed into the next row. How can i use the small input-group and append a button?

Here's the code

```
<div class="input-group-sm mb-3">
  <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Search">
  <div class="input-group-append">
    <button class="btn btn-success" type="submit">Go</button>  
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Read the docs: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.1/components/input-group/#sizing

Both `input-group` and `input-group-sm` should be used.

```
<div class="input-group input-group-sm mb-3">
    <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Search">
    <div class="input-group-append">
        <button class="btn btn-success" type="submit">Go</button>
    </div>
</div>
```

https://codeply.com/go/xQqixpT60a

Comment: Cant make it work the same in Bootstrap 5.1, any suggestion ?